# Differences between in ros recorded intensity of velodyne lidar sensor and calibrated reflectivity?

Tags: ros, lidar

i'm currently confused about the definition of recorded intensity of velodyne lidar senor in ros and calibrated calibrated reflectivity in velodyne user manual. Does the intensity in ros mean the same as calibrated reflectivity in user book?
What i understand is the intensity represents the reflected infrared reflectance normalized by square distance, while reflectivity ist the property of material, maybe their values are the same, but they are physically different?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Modern lidars will sometimes do a secondary measurement that calculates the infrared reflectance of the surface they hit; i.e. energy of the reflected pulse. This is what ROS represents as `intensity` and Velodyne as `calibrated reflectivity`. So to give you a definitive answer, yes, they're actually the same thing.

Comment: Understood, thanks for ur answer, it helps me a lot!